# Apache Spark SQL - Join result is empty

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, apache-spark

if I try to do a join statement with Spark SQL the output result is empty.

```
DataFrame tblA = sql.read().jdbc(URL, "T_A", props);
DataFrame tblB = sql.read().jdbc(URL, "T_B", props);
Column c = tblA.col("id").equalTo( tblB.col("id"));
tblA.join(tblB, c).show();
```

I dont understand why its wrong...

Greetz

Comment: We don't understand what's wrong neither without a data example.

Comment: What data example do you need? I have a Database with the two tables and the tables have both id as primary key for an example. And I want to join them on the id key. And the result is empty. If I do a normal SQL query in the SQL console I got a result.

Comment: Are some IDs the same? Are you sure you want full-join, not i.e. left join?

Comment: Yeah the IDs are the same, i know the names are not a good choose but its only test tables. The join doesnt matter for the first. And I said if I make a join query in a SQL console I receive the result

Comment: I have a similar issue, the id's are there in both dataframes, but the "join on a.id=b.id" is empty result. Interesting fact, if I do a "join on a.id - b.id =0", it works as expected. So, a.id=b.id is false, but a.id-b.id=0 is true.